# Firefox 22 Monitor HTTP traffic in extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, monitor, traffic, gecko

I am currently trying to write a simple Firefox addon for monitoring http traffic.

I searched around a lot and also found some things, but everything was related to Firefox 3.6 and I do not know how it works in later versions, I think in Firefox 4 something was changed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Monitoring_HTTP_activity

Looks good, but I always get, that Components.classes[] is not defined and the Mozilla Addon Builder wont even built the addon with that line.

Does someone know how this works in newer Firefox versions?

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: this is not a thing you can ask here.you should search for it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the objective?  Do you simply want to monitor HTTP traffic or is this a homework assignment?  Unless you have a compelling reason to write your own add-on, you might consider using an existing utility like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/).

Comment: No this is not a homework, I am not even in school at the moment. I want to write my own plugin, because I want to do some Javascript stuff with the response and I havent seen the possibility to hook javascript with those addons. :-/

Answer (score 0):

You should learn the basic of Extension first. But why not don't use httpfox?

Comment: Well the problem is, that I cannot find a proper tutorial :/ Every tutorial says that you should use Components.classes[], but this simply does not work. I don´t use httpfox, because I want to process the traffic with my custom javascript, I don´t really want to output the traffic.